# Conditional format cell based on cell used in formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have cells that I want to highlight based on the cell used in the formula of the cell. Basically I want Excel to look at the formula, and if it is using `"$G$1"` color it blue, and if `$G$1` is replaced with `$H$1` I want it be green.

Here is the formula:

```
=((G4*(1+$G$1)))*(1+$K$1)
```

I tried `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$1,F6))` and just `SEARCH`, but they don't work. I can get it to work on a very basic formula like `G1*2`, but as soon as I put parentheses around it, the conditional formating fails.

Any sugguestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post some screenshots with working and not working examples? Also which version of Excel? You likely need [`FORMULATEXT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/formulatext-function-0a786771-54fd-4ae2-96ee-09cda35439c8) which is available since Excel 2013 (or 2011 for Mac) only.

Comment: Here is an example of it working and not working.

13 ;=+C13*1         TRUE ;=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C13,E12))
14 ;=+(C13+1)*1 FALSE ;=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C13,E13))

13 and 14 are the formula results. And TRUE is where the formula to the right is working, FALSE is where it is not because of the parentheses. 

I tried a FORMULATEXT, but didn't get that working either. But your comment made me relook at it and I got it working. 

Here is the working formula 
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("$H$1",FORMULATEXT(G4)))

Thanks for pointing me back in the right direction. 

Office 365 version, 1804.

Comment: Great you could solve it!  Please post it as an answer so others can learn too.

Comment: @JeffWest,, Y don't you just post the text in comments as a Answer,, you have done it. You can answer your Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Excel 2016 you could use `FORMULATEXT`, to convert the formula to test, and then `SEARCH` within the text.

`A1` would be the location of the formula in the below example, then use this as the condition for the formatting.

```
=SEARCH("$G$1",FORMULATEXT(A1))>0
```